# iOS ARKit ARFaceAnchor export to 3D model file with acutal face size?

Tags: ios, arkit

Is there any method to export my face geometry with real face size????

I tried export with ModelIO then it was success.. but exported vertices in Model file is too small

Comment: Show your code, please)

Comment: The vertices in ARKit are defined in meters. A lot of other graphics programs use coordinates in millimeters, so you probably want to convert to millimeters before exporting by scaling the model by 1000. Other than this, the dimensions should be equivalent to what you see in ARKit.

Comment: Can you please share your code how you had exported it. Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just scale * 1000 solved my problem.

`faceNode.scale = SCNVector3Make(1000,1000,1000)`